# Finiding out which radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

With Rails radio_button_tag and form_tag I have created some radio buttons that its page source looks like this:

```
  <div id = "selections">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pharmacy" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="HBJZRoNElQ/1Ll/axFdXZAsD+71BLB6eKwmliJHUgDc=" /></div>
        <input id="age_child" name="age" type="radio" value="child" />
        <label for="age_child">Group by something</label>
        <input id="age_adult" name="age" type="radio" value="adult" />
        <label for="age_adult">Group by something else</label>
  </form></div>
```

So now in my JavaScript I need to know which Radio button is selected and know its associated value. What is the way to do this? I am very new to Rails and jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var value = $('#selections form input:radio:checked').val();
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/Trk6W/15/

Comment: your previous one worked too,  what is the difference with the new one you updated? the other was has a bug or something?

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark The new one is little more specific to your `selections` div and form.. so it only selects radios from inside of your specified form

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the value on change of radio then you can attach a change event handler to it.  Then use `this.value` to access the value of the selected radio.

```
$('form input[type=radio]').on('change' , function() {
     var $this = $(this);

     console.log( 'value --' + this.value  )
});
```

Comment: thanks, no not to the change , I am clicking on some CHARTS and before I show new charts I want to know what have they selected in the radio button so be able to act based on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var value = $(':radio:checked[name=age]').val()
```

The selectors (that start with a colon) narrow down exactly what element you're evaluating, and the pseudoselector "[name=age]" filters the result further in case you have more than one radio group on your page.